# creating and viewing object with angular + web api. Front End structure

Tags: angular

I want to create object for example House and have ability to create House, view House, update House.

What should be the structure of folders and files in angular ?

House folder with components create , view , update ?

Also I want house to be created using link

```
site.com/house/create
```

While view house should be

```
site.com/houses/123 where 123 is house ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would crate a `HouseModule` with 4 Components:

- HouseComponent
- ViewHouseComponent
- CreateHouseComponent
- UpdateHouseComponent

Also that's how your `house-routing` could look like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'house', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'house', component: HouseComponent},
  { path: 'house/:id', component: ViewHouseComponent },
  { path: 'house/create', component: CreateHouseComponent},
  { path: 'house/update', component: UpdateHouseComponent},
];
```